# Why does the execution time change when I use a different programming language for the main routine?

Tags: execution, ada

I am working with physical modelling. The model in this case is written in C. When I call the model I usually do that from Ada. However, I tried to write it in C also and I noticed that the when I use Ada the model takes roughly 30% more time to execute than using C!

Can someone explain why this is so? Why does Ada takes longer. I want to point out that the main routine in Ada that calls the model does nothing except for calling the model and moves data to the input array which is about 100 elements. Also the model itself is pretty computaionally heavy so the difference of 30% is remarkable.

Also the same compilation flags are used in both cases. Should one expect a difference when the main routine is written in different languages. If so, why?

Comment: How long does the whole program take to execute? and what proportion of that is the model? An Ada program has to initialize the runtime system and perform elaboration - though I wouldn't expect that to be noticeable.

Comment: Is it possible to boil the example down to a very small testcase, where the C model does something simple and non-proprietary like adding 1 to each element? It should either exhibit the same performance problem, or, perhaps, reveal a mistake in the current test...

Comment: But even if the ADA program takes time to initialize runtime system, that would probably also be true if it was written in C?

Lets say we run the program for 10 seconds when using C as the main routine. Going to ADA as main routine now takes 13 seconds even though the hardcore calculations really are made in the model written in C.

I will analyze some simple examples as you suggest and see if I can find out anything more.

Comment: If you edit the simple example into the question, with compile command, others can reproduce the problem and maybe help.

Comment: I just tried a C "model" which increments `__volatile int x = 0;` in a loop where the iteration count is supplied by the main program. The Ada and C main programs took the same time (4.8s with an iteration count of 2e9) within experimental error (1%).

Answer (score 1):

Given the information we have so far, any answer is speculation; but here's one speculation:

On some operating systems (notably Debian and derivatives at the moment) the default installation of Gnat is a different version of gcc (gcc-4.6) than the default gcc itself. 
Alternatively if you downloaded [Gnat Libre Edition 2012](http://libre.adacore.com) it will have installed its own gcc version alongside your system's own gcc.

In either case, building the combined Ada/C program (e.g. with Gnatmake) may have used a different C compiler version than the pure C build; in which case it is likely that the difference in speed is purely down to the different C compiler versions!

To test this hypothesis you can (a) find out exactly which compiler versions you are using - and name them in the question! - and (b) force the pure C version to build with the same compiler version ( e.g. with a CC=gcc-4.6 flag) - if this is the problem, the speed difference will vanish.

My solution - which is non-trivial - is to build a new gcc (I'm currently using 4.7.2) from source, with --enable-languages=ada,c,c++

However there may be other solutions - for example, you may need different compile flags to select the same actual behaviour; docs for the different C compiler versions should offer some clues.

Or wait a little while and upgrade; Debian have plans to bring their Gnat release back into sync with the rest of gcc. There was one key Ada/C app that was holding this process up through incompatibilities (ironically, between its C portion and newer GCC versions!), but that app has now been updated.

Answer (score -1):

Without some example I cannot say why.
The most likely explanation  is the translation of code is more of a transliteration -- and therefore likely optimized around C's low-level idiosyncrasies, among which is a tendency towards aliasing.

The Array should not be copying, as Ada compilers are smart enough to pass by reference under-the-hood. One thing that might, but shouldn't, be slowing you down is the interface between C and Ada.

---

*Should one expect a difference when the main routine is written in different languages. If so, why?*

That's very dependent on how the routine is written -- if it's written to make use of implementation-dependent features then it's not [guaranteed] to do the same thing even in the original language... so then we can't, in the most general case, say that we should expect the routine's timing to be the same in another language.

So then your question only makes sense when not depending on any implementation's idiosyncrasies.

Comment: But OP hasn't translated the body of the program, which is still in C; only the main program.

Comment: In this case the ADA layer does not really make anything except for calling the C-function, i.e. the model. Since the ADA-layer should not take computational power it seems like the interface between ADA and C slows down the program. But, if the interface would be the cause of the problem in this case, what is takig time there? In my world jumping from one function and back should not take any time at all? Or am I wrong here?

Comment: You're right it shouldn't take measurably extra time - something else seems to be going on. Simon pointed one possibility : if the model takes 0.01 seconds, and the Ada RTS is taking 0.003 seconds to initialise, you might interpret that one-time cost as a 30% overhead.